# How to add an image to a canvas, scaled to size?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I can add a local image to my canvas. My problem though is that I can only scale the image by something like `0.5` but this isn't very helpful because images are always different. How might I have the image scale to say 400px wide, but the rest **resize proportionally** so that no matter the size of the chosen image, things fit and it isn't a guessing game (currently I have a link to an image resizer, I'm trying to remove the need)?

I'm using fabricjs 1.7.21.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
canvas.setHeight(616);
canvas.setWidth(446);

// New Photo to Canvas
document.getElementById('imgLoader').onchange = function handleImage(e) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = event.target.result;
    imgObj.onload = function() {
      var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
      image.set({
        left: 10,
        top: 10,
      }).scale(0.5);
      canvas.add(image);
    }
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.21/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="btn btn-default" id="imgLoader">
            <span class="oi oi-image"></span> Add Image<input type="file" hidden>
        </label>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: I believe that scaleToWidth/scaleToHeight may be what you are looking for.  You can find the documentation at http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#scaleToWidth.

Comment: @Ben this is exactly correct. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scaleToWidth`/`scaleToHeight` was what I was looking for. You can find the documentation [here](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#scaleToWidth).

Props to @Ben who commented this. I wanted to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
canvas.setHeight(616);
canvas.setWidth(446);

// New Photo to Canvas
document.getElementById('imgLoader').onchange = function handleImage(e) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = event.target.result;
    imgObj.onload = function() {
      var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
      image.width = 400;
      image.height = 400;
      image.set({
        left: 10,
        top: 10,
   
      });
      canvas.add(image);
    }
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: Hi. I'm actually trying to scale the image proportionally, not designate a specific height AND width; just a width—this is because not all images are square or even the same size. I tried rephrasing my question some to better reflect this.